# Gmock: returning an invalid value

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

The strange behavior of the return value of the function when using the enum class, before that, int was used and the test passed successfully.

```
enum class rvalue
{
    ok = 0,
    bad = 1,
    other = 2,
};

class Speeder
{
public slots:
    rvalue Run(int speed)
    {
        if (speed < 0)
            return rvalue::bad;
        else if (speed > 1000)
            return rvalue::bad;
        else if (speed > 1)
            return rvalue::other;

        return rvalue::ok;
    }

};

class MockSpeeder : public Speeder
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(Run, rvalue(int speed));
};

TEST(Mytest, RunTest)
{
    MockSpeeder mspeeder;
    Speeder speeder;
    EXPECT_CALL(mspeeder, Run(testing::_))
        .Times(1);

    auto a = mspeeder.Run(100); // The result is rvalue::ok. Why?
    auto b = speeder.Run(100); // Result is rvalue::other. 
    EXPECT_TRUE(a == b);
}
```

As a result, a variable called a is equal to rvalue::ok, although the code shows that such a result is clearly impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless specified otherwise, mock would return default value.

It doesn't call base class implementation.